# Exception: Action 16.0.81.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence failed

Tags: 2016, 2019, upgrade

I am upgrading SharePoint 2016 to 2019 when i mount SP2016 Content database in SP2019 farm i found below errors.
SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content01

Exception: Cannot find the object "dbo.ImmedSubscriptions" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteScript(TextReader textReader, Int32 commandTimeout)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseAction.Upgrade(ISchemaUpgradeAction schemaAction)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseAction.Upgrade()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()

Upgrade [SPContentDatabase Name=[WSS_Content01] failed.
Inner Exception: Cannot find the object "dbo.ImmedSubscriptions" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Exception: Action 16.0.81.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence failed.
[image]

Comment: which account you are trying to execute this upgrade ?

Comment: SharePoint Farm account

Comment: and when i tried 
Dismount the content database which has  issue.
Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard to get the farm patched successfully.
Mount the unmounted database again,
Then run the below cmdlet

Get-SPContentDatabase –Identity WSS_Content_Name | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase 
again i faced the same issue above error
Exception: Action 16.0.81.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence failed.

Comment: Your SP Farm account, SP Admin account and the rest of the service accounts, are they in a custom Organizational Unit ?

Comment: do you use a service account to handle the connection with SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I fixed the issue by adding dbo permissions to SharePoint Farm account that has  db_owner of this database